# Thread locks occuring using boost::thread. What's wrong with my condition variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, condition-variable

I wrote a Link class for passing data between two nodes in a network. I've implemented it with two deques (one for data going from node 0 to node 1, and the other for data going from node 1 to node 0). I'm trying to multithread the application, but I'm getting threadlocks. I'm trying to prevent reading from and writing to the same deque at the same time. In reading more about how I originally implemented this, I think I'm using the condition variables incorrectly (and maybe shouldn't be using the boolean variables?). Should I have two mutexes, one for each deque? Please help if you can. Thanks!

```
class Link {
public:
// other stuff...
void push_back(int sourceNodeID, Data newData);
void get(int destinationNodeID, std::vector<Data> &linkData);

private:
// other stuff...
std::vector<int> nodeIDs_;
// qVector_ has two deques, one for Data from node 0 to node 1 and 
// one for Data from node 1 to node 0
std::vector<std::deque<Data> > qVector_; 
void initialize(int nodeID0, int nodeID1);

boost::mutex mutex_;
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::condition_variable> > readingCV_;
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::condition_variable> > writingCV_;
std::vector<bool> writingData_;
std::vector<bool> readingData_;
};
```

The push_back function:

```
void Link::push_back(int sourceNodeID, Data newData)
{
int idx;
if (sourceNodeID == nodeIDs_[0]) idx = 1;
else 
{
    if (sourceNodeID == nodeIDs_[1]) idx = 0;
    else throw runtime_error("Link::push_back: Invalid node ID");
}

boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
// pause to avoid multithreading collisions
while (readingData_[idx]) readingCV_[idx]->wait(lock);

writingData_[idx] = true;
qVector_[idx].push_back(newData);
writingData_[idx] = false;
writingCV_[idx]->notify_all();
}
```

The get function:

```
void Link::get(int destinationNodeID,
std::vector<Data> &linkData)
{
int idx;
if (destinationNodeID == nodeIDs_[0]) idx = 0;
else 
{
    if (destinationNodeID == nodeIDs_[1]) idx = 1;
    else throw runtime_error("Link::get: Invalid node ID");
}

boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
// pause to avoid multithreading collisions
while (writingData_[idx]) writingCV_[idx]->wait(lock);
readingData_[idx] = true;

std::copy(qVector_[idx].begin(),qVector_[idx].end(),back_inserter(linkData));
qVector_[idx].erase(qVector_[idx].begin(),qVector_[idx].end());
readingData_[idx] = false;
readingCV_[idx]->notify_all();
return;
}
```

and here's initialize (in case it's helpful)

```
void Link::initialize(int nodeID0, int nodeID1)
{
readingData_ = std::vector<bool>(2,false);
writingData_ = std::vector<bool>(2,false);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    readingCV_.push_back(make_shared<boost::condition_variable>());
    writingCV_.push_back(make_shared<boost::condition_variable>());
}
nodeIDs_.reserve(2);
nodeIDs_.push_back(nodeID0);
nodeIDs_.push_back(nodeID1);
qVector_.reserve(2);
qVector_.push_back(std::deque<Data>());
qVector_.push_back(std::deque<Data>());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm trying to multithread the application, but I'm getting threadlocks.*

What is a "threadlock"?  It's difficult to see what your code is trying to accomplish.  Consider, first, your push_back() code, whose synchronized portion looks like this:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);

while (readingData_[idx]) readingCV_[idx]->wait(lock);

writingData_[idx] = true;
qVector_[idx].push_back(newData);
writingData_[idx] = false;
writingCV_[idx]->notify_all();
```

Your `writingData[idx]` boolean starts off as false, and becomes true only momentarily while a thread *has the mutex locked*.  By the time the mutex is released, it is false again. So for any *other* thread that has to wait to acquire the mutex, `writingData[idx]` will *never* be true.

But in your get() code, you have

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
// pause to avoid multithreading collisions
while (writingData_[idx]) writingCV_[idx]->wait(lock);
```

By the time a thread gets the lock on the mutex, `writingData[idx]` is back to false and so the while loop (and wait on the CV) is *never* entered.

An exactly symmetric analysis applies to the `readingData[idx]` boolean, which also is *always* false outside the mutex lock.

So your condition variables are *never* waited on. You need to completely rethink your design.

Start with one mutex per queue (the deque is overkill for simply passing data), and for each queue associate a condition variable with the queue being non-empty.  The `get()` method will thus wait until the queue is non-empty,  which will be signalled in the `push_back()` method.  Something like this (untested code):

```
template <typename Data>
class BasicQueue
{
public:
    void push( Data const& data )
    {
        boost::unique_lock  _lock( mutex_ );
        queue_.push_back( data );
        not_empty_.notify_all();
    }

    void get ( Data& data )
    {
        boost::unique_lock  _lock( mutex_ );
        while ( queue_.size() == 0 )
            not_empty_.wait( _lock ); // this releases the mutex
        // mutex is reacquired here, with queue_.size() > 0
        data = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop_front();         
    }

private:
    std::queue<Data>            queue_;
    boost::mutex                mutex_;
    boost::condition_variable   not_empty_;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I meant "deadlock" -- that's what I get for writing a question at midnight. Also, I certainly need to clean up this implementation, but I thought this was the way the boolean variables that a condition variable were tied to were supposed to work. I wanted to allow reading in `get()` to be performed any time that another thread isn't writing to the same deque. So, I only set `writingData` to true when a thread is actually writing data. Don't the boolean flags needed to be protected by a locked mutex so reading and writing don't happen at the same time?

Comment: You are setting it back to false *within the scope of the same lock*!  By the time *another* thread examines the boleoan, which this new thread can do only *after* acquiring the mutex, which is *after* the first thread has released it, the boolean is false again.

Comment: You may be confused about what CVs are for.  When a thread waits on a CV, it is (atomically) releasing the mutex so that some other thread can get the mutex, operate on the shared variables and (possibly) signal the condition that the first thread is waiting for.  A CV is not for "informing" some other thread about what this thread might or might not be doing.  Please look at the code I've added to my answer.  Note how the reading thread has to *wait* for some data to appear on the queue, an operation that only a writing thread can perform (and then signal that fact).

Comment: There is no deadlock in the code you've presented.  There may be a lot of spinning (e.g. your `get()` function has no guarantee that there is anything in the deque.)

Comment: Clearly I was confused about what CVs are for. I was thinking that whenever there was a lock, a CV was needed. Thanks for helping me sort through this. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You need two mutexes.  Your deadlocks are almost certainly a result of contention on the single mutex.  If you break into your running program with a debugger you will see where the threads are hanging.  Also I don't see why you would need the bools. (EDIT: It may be possible to come up with a design that uses a single mutex but it's simpler and safer to stick with one mutex per shared data structure)

A rule of thumb would be to have one mutex per shared data structure you are trying to protect.  That mutex guards the data structure against concurrent access and provides thread safety.  In your case one mutex per deque.  E.g.:

```
class SafeQueue
{
private:
  std::deque<Data> q_;
  boost::mutex m_;
  boost::condition_variable v_;

public:
  void push_back(Data newData)
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_);
    q_.push_back(newData);
    // notify etc.
  }
// ...
};
```

In terms of notification via condition variables see here:

[Using condition variable in a producer-consumer situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379806/using-condition-variable-in-a-producer-consumer-situation)

So there would also be one `condition_variable` per object which the producer would notify and the consumer would wait on.  Now you can create two of these queues for communicating in both directions.  Keep in mind that with only two threads you can still deadlock if both threads are blocked (waiting for data) and both queues are empty.

Comment: thanks for your help, as well. I certainly need to simplify this a lot (and read more!).